# Zapier update In podio says i don't have permission but clearly I do

Tags: permissions, zapier, podio

Also checked box in podio app to allow users to update and modify items.

Put still get this error in zapier when trying to update
[image]

```
"The app returned "The user with id 1653273 does
not have the right update on item with id 6". It looks like your
connected account doesn't have permission to complete this step. You
should contact the administrator for your account and make sure you
have the needed permissions."
```

Answer (score 0):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

That looks like an issue on the Podio end that Zapier is surfacing. I'd try reconnecting the account in Zapier (maybe you need a fresh token to pick up the permission changes?). If that doesn't work, Podio support is probably your best bet for getting an answer. They'll have the tools to troubleshoot your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Pavlo here, from Podio team :)

Something is wrong with your config, I'm 100500% sure that item with id `6` is not yours and you don't have rights to update it :) Please debug your flow and ensure that you are trying to modify correct item.

Comment: Pavlo... can you explain why you say that? i see below the zapier guy is saying i should disconnect and reconect.   Will try that... and see what happens.

Comment: Because Podio has >1 billion items, and there are no chances item with id `6` belongs to you. I'd expect item id's that you should operate with, to be more like `123456789`.

Comment: I think he is assigning AppItemId as item id

Answer (score 0):

i didn't realize item id was a universal id within podio and not just something that would reference in that app. so id 6 seemed reasonable from that perspective as that app only had a couple items in it to test.  so i have not gotten the right value from the zapier item look up go to to the zapier item update and it worked flawlessly.